# Request is not getting into views, but its shows the corret url

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Form is loaded in html page but when i click submit button,it shows nothing(No HttpResponse which i used in views). But it show url(http://localhost:8000/datainsert )as i described in urls.py. Please point out what's wrong in my code.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Test
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Test
    fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def datainsert(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponse('Saved')
    return HttpResponse('Not saved')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from .views import index, datainsert, testing

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^datainsert', views.datainsert, name='datainsert'),
]
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Web</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="{% url 'myapp:datainsert' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using? Also, change form method to lowercase "post". In your index.html

Comment: thanks thomas for your reply, i forget to put $ for my empty url. Now its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't terminate your empty URL.

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
```

Currently it matches every possible path.